# unwanted constructor calls before main()

Tags: c++

I am working on some multi-thread code with *pthreads*. When I discovered some memory-leaks (via *valgrind*), I simply added some

```
cout << " new [some name of class for me]" << endl;
```

in part of constructors, because I thought I have removed all of them. This revealed that part of them are launched before ***main().*** I have removed everything from main(), so it looks like:

```
int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

Even without any ***#includes*** those constructors are still invoked. I think nothing from the previous code should be invoked in this case. I used *"project clean"* option in eclipse and try to delete binaries (*Debug/Release*). Nothing helps ..

What is the purpose of that? What else I can do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have static instances of classes, or global instances?

Comment: As people say, it's a static or global instance somewhere, just add _abort()_ to the constructor, rebuild, run, see in what stack it crashes and cleanup the respective path

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`global` and `static` variables are initialized before `main`. Except for the `static` variables declared inside a function. They are initialized on a first call. So I think you should look at the static and global variables

Comment: ok, that was it.. but they are destroyed normally, so this is not the cause of memory-leak. Thanks for advice. I need to seek further ..